# Do I need to respond to a card (with a gift)?

Tags: professionalism, politics

I got married recently. We tried to keep it as quiet as possible in order to avoid the drama that would typically come along with with such an event, but I had to eventually had to share it with HR in order to add my wife to our insurance plan.

Long story short I received a card today with signatures from most of the local office (around 75 people) and a not insignificant amount of cash - roughly equivalent to two nice dinners for the two of us.

Should I acknowledge this, or parts of this? It seems excessive to email-blast my local office with a thank you note for the card, and I'm not 100% sure who I would send a thank you for the money to - C?O's and VPs would be my first guess.

Comment: Just thank everyone the next time you see them -- or send a note to be shared at the next meeting or posted on whatever you use for other announcements.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the best answer to above question can be found by considering the opposite situation, Suppose someone else in your team got married recently and you all have given a card and some cash gift to that person. In that case "Would like to receive a thank you card or mail from that person ? Would you like it to happen in team meeting ? or whatever ?"

Understanding the alternate case gives you clear understanding of your workplace ethics and culture. You can also take a clue from someone who faced similar situation recently.

I would suggest a brief mail with some sweets (chocolates etc.) like the one below..

> Hello All,
>
> I & (your spouse name here) really appreciate your wishes and gift.
>   Please stop by my desk and share sweets.
>
> Thanks once again,
>
> (Your & your spouse name here)

Please note that above mail is just the simplest template, you can customize it with your own words.

You are right that people sitting at C?O positions may be too busy for these mails. But if they spend few minutes on your marriage gift card (cash) discussions they too deserve a "Thank You note". This will be a good gesture from your side and even if C?Os don't come just think that they are really too busy.

Comment: I think this is the right answer - what usually happens is someone will bring in some sort of token breakfast item. So "thanks very much for the well wishing, there's donuts in the kitchen" (more eloquently put but you get the idea).

Answer (score 2):

We have often had people just fill out one Thank You note (Yes the paper kind) and post it on the refrigerator door in the break room.

Answer (score 1):

Just send one or two sentence email thanking everyone for their support. Try to send that email during the off-hours to minimize any stress on the mail servers. And make sure that your email has text only - NO GRAPHICS, NO PICTURES.